# How to convert existing async task to Volley in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I have code like:

```
private class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        .....
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object...params) {
        getList();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        .....
    }
}

private void getList() {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        if(json != null) {
            .....
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        .....
    }
}
```

How can I convert it to its [Volley library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) equivalent?

P.S: I know about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675072/volley-and-asynctask), but unfortunately it does not help much.

Comment: see [Android: Getting Started with Volley](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-getting-started-with-volley/) maybe help you in implementing Volley lib

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948191/android-send-post-request-using-volley-and-receive-in-php/25948689#25948689 Use the custom request for json that I made