# How do I reference my JSON onResponse in my postexecute method?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to create an async task for my JsonArray, as it is skipping frames and lagging. I created an asyncTask class put in the parameters and i called my Json request in the do in background , however, how do I now reference my Json onresponse in my postexecute method?

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL,String,JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(URL... params) {
            JsonRequestMethod();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray response) {

        }
    }
}


private void JsonRequestMethod() {
            mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
            //intitalize Volley Singleton request key
            mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
            //2 types of requests an Array request and an Object Request
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    listblogs.clear();
                    listblogs=parseJSONResponse(response);
                    mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(listblogs);


                    System.out.println("it worked!!!");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        ArrayList<Blogs> blogsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String points = currentQuestions.getString("points");
                String ID=currentQuestions.getString("id");
                String studentId = currentQuestions.getString("studentId");
                String DateCreated=currentQuestions.getString("created");
                long time=Long.parseLong(DateCreated.trim());
                data.append(text + "\n" + points + "\n");
                System.out.println(data);
                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setId(ID);
                blogs.setMstudentId(studentId);
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setPoints(points);
                //The dateCreated was off by 1 hour so 3600000 ms where added=1hour, (UPDATE)
                blogs.setDateCreated(getTimeAgo(time));
                System.out.println(time+"time");


                listblogs.add(blogs);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listblogs;
}
```

Comment: A volley request shouldn't cause lag, it would be in your parsing which you can put in an async task.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675072/volley-and-asynctask

Comment: @zgc7009 I/O should never be run on a UI thread. Volley simply automatically runs requests asynchronously.

Comment: Volley manages its own thread pool @chrylis that is the point of initializing a request queue. The response (the parsing part) needs to be handled explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your volley request is already asynchronous, that's why it has listener interfaces like `onResponse()` and `onErrorResponse()`.  You don't need it in the `AsyncTask` at all.  Call your volley request from the UI thread, and use your `AsyncTask` to parse the JSON.  For example:

1. Call your volley request.
2. In `onResponse()` from your volley request, create your AsyncTask to handle parsing.
3. Parse the JSON in your `doInBackground()` method, "return" the result of the parsing.
4. Your `onPostExecute()` will receive the parsing "result," and you can do what you want with it there.

To go even further, you could implement a listener interface for your AsyncTask as well, something like `onJSONParsed()`, then you could set logic in your UI thread (where you called your volley request), to handle the 100% finished response.  For example:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL,String,ArrayList<Blogs>> {
    // Listener member variable.
    private OnJSONParsedListener mOnJSONParsedListener;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Blog> doInBackground(URL... params) {
        // Parse JSON.
        ArrayList<Blogs> blogsList = parseJSON(response);

        // Pass the blogs list to the onPostExecute method.
        return blogsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Blogs> blogsList) {
        // Invoke listener, if present.
        if (mOnJSONParsedListener != null)
            mOnJSONParsedListener.onJSONParsed(blogsList);
    }

    // Listener interface.
    public interface OnJSONParsedListener {
        void onJSONParsed(ArrayList<Blogs> blogsList);
    }

    // Setter for listener interface member variable.
    public void setOnJSONParsedListener(OnJSONParsedListener listener) {
        mOnJSONParsedListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Then in your UI thread.

```
// Call your volley request.
mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();

//intitalize Volley Singleton request key
mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

//2 types of requests an Array request and an Object Request
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        // Create AsyncTask.
        MyTask parseJSONTask = new MyTask();

        // Set listener interface.
        parseJSONTask.setOnJSONParsedListener(new MyTask.OnJSONParsedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onJSONParsed(ArrayList<Blogs> blogsList) {
                // Do stuff with your blogs list.
                mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(blogsList);

                // It worked!
                System.out.println("it worked!!!");
            }
        }

        // Execute.
        parseJSONTask.execute(response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
});
mRequestQueue.add(request);
```

Hope this helps.